# Magento 2.3 - GIF Images , Animation is not working on frontend 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, product-images

Magneto 2.3 GIF image is working in admin panel ,but not working in fronted ,how to solve this?

Comment: Is the GIF saved against a product?  Could be the magento cache re-rendering the image as a JPEG.

Comment: yes Dominic Xigen ,so how can it be sorted